# Having trouble adding a background to the top of an image without it bleeding past the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying for a while to figure out how to add an overlay to an image on a site I'm woking on. I can't seem to get the overlay to not bleed past the image. I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the grid layout.

[image: image with overflow problem]

Here's my HTML

```
    <div id="feature-section" class="row hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-sm-6 feature-desktop">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="img/feature_img.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <h3 class="feature-section">For Business Owners</h3>
                        <p class="feature-title">Week in Review: $1 Trillion, Moelis and Nasdaq</p>
                        <hr class="feature-rule">
                        <ul class="feature-tags">
                            <li class="feature-tag">Business Owners,</li>
                            <li class="feature-tag">Negotiation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- END #feature-section .row -->
```

And the corresponding CSS (minus the bootstrap stuff)

```
    .feature-desktop {
    position: relative;
    }

    .feature-text {
    background: url("../img/lg-pattern.png") rgba(255,255,255, 0.5) repeat;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

I think this is because the width of the containing div is larger than the image. but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The padding is being added to the 100% width, that's why it's bleeding over.

Comment: Do you have a width set on a containing parent element? If your width of your bg image is less than your container (or less than the width of the text area) it's going to bleed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires one change to the markup (removing the container around the image). Unfortunately I don't see a clean way of solving the issue without touching the HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/g8BEW/

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#feature-section {
    width: 430px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.feature-desktop {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.feature-text {
    background: url("//placehold.it/5x200") rgba(255,255,255, 0.5) repeat;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="feature-section" class="row hidden-xs">
   <div class="col-sm-6 feature-desktop">
     <img src="//placehold.it/400x600" alt="">
     <div class="feature-text">
       <h3 class="feature-section">For Business Owners</h3>
       <p class="feature-title">Week in Review: $1 Trillion, Moelis and Nasdaq</p>
       <hr class="feature-rule">
       <ul class="feature-tags">
         <li class="feature-tag">Business Owners,</li>
         <li class="feature-tag">Negotiation</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```